# Is there a way to set the default TTL for multicast packets?

Tags: defaults, multicast

[This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667096/how-to-change-the-default-ttl-of-tcp-ip-packets) Provided some valuable insight on how to set the default TTL for IP packets on a system.  I would like to do the same thing, but for multicast packets.  I do not know if this is possible.

This [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) indicates that application code can set the multicast TTL with a call to setsockopt() with the flag IP_MULTICAST_TTL, stating further that default value is 1.  I want to know if there is a way to set that value at the system level.